# Ubuntu 12.10 freezes at reboot

Tags: freeze, reboot, bumblebee, aspire

I just moved from Windows 7 to Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Acer Aspire E1-471G laptop, the hardware is listed below:

- CPU: Ivy Bridge i3-3110M
- Graphics: NVIDIA GT 630M & Intel HD4000

Ubuntu operated very well at first, but then it began to freeze at the purple background when the progress bar passed one dot of five when I shutdown or rebooted from the desktop. The command reboot from the terminal freezes too, but shutdown from the terminal is OK.

I have installed Bumblebee and GNOME. I also installed Windows, and used to use Ubuntu 12.04, but it froze randomly, especially when browsing the internet. It was said that Ubuntu 12.10 could avoid that problem, so I installed 12.10 instead of 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try `shutdown -r now` in terminal.  This worked for me when I had issues with `reboot` leaving me in run level 1 on a few different servers running 13.04.

Comment: The command shutdown -r now doesn't work.